# Proving a transformation preserves a property

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, projection

Let $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1/(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i),x_2/(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i),\ldots,x_n/(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i))$ be in $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$, and $X$ be a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$.

I was trying to prove if the following holds:

$$
hull(f(X))=f(hull(X))$$
where $hull(X)$ is the convex hull of $X$. $f$ is a projection onto probability simplex in $n$ dimensions, but I was not able to prove the equality.

Another question that I tried to prove is, does this transformation preserve convexity?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the second question is yes, the image under $f$ of a convex set is convex. In general, the image of a segment $AB$ under $f$ is the segment $f(A)f(B)$ (provided $f$ is well-defined throughout the segment $AB$, which is certainly the case if $A, B \in (0,+\infty)^n$).

Let $H$ be the hyperplane $x_1 + \dots + x_n = 1$. Then $f$ is the central projection onto $H$ with respect to the origin $O$. The domain of $f$ is the complement of the hyperplane $H_0 \colon x_1 + \dots + x_n = 0$, that is, the union of the two open half-spaces determined by $H_0$.

Now assume the segment $AB$ is contained in the domain of $f$, i.e., $A$ and $B$ are on the same side of $H_0$. If $O, A, B$ lie on the same line, there is nothing to prove, as $f$ is constant on the segment $AB$. Otherwise, the whole problem is situated within the plane $\alpha$ through $O, A, B$.

Let $l, l_0$ be the lines of intersection of $\alpha$ with $H, H_0$. Then $A, B$ are points in $\alpha$ on the same side of $l_0$, which we can assume without loss of generality to be the same side where $l$ is. The problem is to see that if $C$ is a point between $A$ and $B$, then $f(C)$ is between $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ on line $l$ (and all points of the segment $f(A)f(B)$ are of this form).

Now this is reduced to a well-known fact of plane geometry: given three rays $r_1$, $r_2$ and $r_3$ all in the same plane, if at least one segment drawn from $r_1$ to $r_2$ intersects $r_3$, then *all* segments drawn from $r_1$ to $r_2$ intersect $r_3$.

It is enough to apply this fact to the rays $r_1 = OA$, $r_2 = OB$, $r_3 = OC$ and the segments $AB$, $f(A)f(B)$.

To answer the first question, it is enough to prove that if $C$ is a convex subset of $H$, then the portion of $f^{-1}(C)$ lying in a chosen half-space with respect to $H_0$ is also convex. This can be given a similar proof by restricting to a plane as above. Then it is enough to see that the region lying between two rays is convex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. 

I could not follow the following: Now assume the segment $AB$ is contained in the domain of $f$, i.e., $A$ and $B$ are on the same side of $H_0$.", specifically $A$ and $B$ being on the same side of $H_0$, and is the plane $\alpha$ defined through the three points $0, A, B?$? Thank you.

Comment: Saying that the segment $AB$ is contained in the domain of $f$ means that it doesn't intersect $H_0$. That's the same as saying that $A$ and $B$ are in the same half-space determined by $H_0$. Yes, $\alpha$ is the plane determined by $O$, $A$ and $B$.